# How to display particular content at particular times in php?

Tags: php, time, timezone

I am working on a website in which I want to display particular content at particular times in php.

From Monday 6PM EST(Eastern Standard Time) to Friday 6PM EST(Eastern Standard Time), I want particular content to be displayed. For that I am using the following logic.

```
$arradate = strtolower(date('D'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
$nowtime = date('H:i:s');
$tue_thu = array('tue','wed','thu');

if (in_array($arradate, $tue_thu) || ($arradate == 'mon' && $nowtime > '17:59:59') || ($arradate == 'fri' && $nowtime < '17:59:59')) {
echo "Hello World";
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there is anything wrong in the code as it didn't work on Thursday. I am on EST and the server is set on UTC.

Comment: The first line grabs the date before setting timezone. That could be an issue.

Comment: @Bryan That is one issue. Is there any other changes I need to make ?

Comment: @Bryan It didn't work on Thursday.

Comment: @Bryan I am wondering the way I am comparing time in if block is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the logic. `DateTime` objects are comparable, so you can directly check if a moment of time is after/before another one:

```php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone( 'America/Toronto' );
$start    = ( new DateTime( 'monday this week', $timezone ) )->setTime( 18, 0 );
$end      = ( new DateTime( 'friday this week', $timezone ) )->setTime( 18, 0 );
$now      = new DateTime( 'now', $timezone );

if ( $now > $start && $now < $end ) {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```